# Number of vectors required to get the whole null space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm interested in finding the null space of the below matrix,

$A=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 \\ 3 & 6 & 8 & 10\end{array}\right]$

Reducing to echelon form we've
$U=\left[\begin{array}{llll}1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]$

Using two free variables, I get two vectors in the null space as
$\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{array}{r}-2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$ and $\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{array}{r}2 \\ 0 \\ -2 \\ 1\end{array}\right]$.

Their linear combination will also be in the null space but how do I know that their combination will fill the entire null space of matrix $A$ ?

Comment: The reduced echelon form exactly answers this. So the nullspace must be $2$-dimensional. A more natural basis would be your first $x$ and $y=(0,1,-2,1)^T$.

Comment: Hi sir,  I couldn't understand how you said that the nullspace must be 2 D

Comment: Rank plus nullity is $4$, and by the reduced echelon form we know what the rank is, right?

Comment: Yes understood it. I had not studied about nullity, the question was before that section. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) we have that the rank plus the nullity equals the dimension of the whole space. In this case the rank of the matrix is $2$ (number of pivots in the reduced matrix) and the full space is $4$ so the nullity must be $4-2=2$.